# Ordenar objetos de una lista por diveros criterios?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, pycharm, ordenamiento

Se ordenar objetos de una lista por un criterio del atributo, utilizando el método `sort()` y añadiendo el método `__it__` en la clase, pero si quiero ordenarlo por diversos criterios, es decir que me lo ordene por longitud de `self.AnteseList = []` y por el nombre la regla `self.N_regla` en los caso que el valor de la longitud sean iguales. No se como hacerlo.

muestro la siguiente clase

```
class BR:

def __init__(self, nom, antesesor, concecuencias, inserir, eliminar):
    self.N_regla = nom                 #str
    self.AnteseSTR = antesesor      #str
    self.AnteseList = []
    self.Concecuencia = concecuencias   #str
    self.AddElement = inserir           #list
    self.DelElement = eliminar          #list

    if self.AnteseSTR != '':
        self.generList()

def __str__(self):
    return '{0}  antesedentes:{1} concecuencia:{2}'.format(self.N_reglas,self.Anteserores,self.Concecuencia)

def __repr__(self):
    return self.__str__()

def __lt__(self, other):
    return len(self.AnteseList) < len(other.AnteseList)

def generList(self):

    self.AnteseList = self.AnteseSTR.split('^')
```

Comment: ¿La idea es que ordene por longitud de AnteseList y si son iguales use N_regla (orden lexicográfico)?

Comment: Sí, es posible hacer eso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque se puede implementar mediante condicionales, una técnica común es genera una tupla con los atributos a comparar de ambos objetos y compara las tuplas:

```
class Foo:
    self.nombre: str = ""
    self.edad: int = 0

    def __lt__(self, other: Foo) -> bool:
        return (self.edad, self.nombre) < (other.edad, other.nombre)
```

Algunas observaciones sobre tu código:

- No es recomendable que `__repr__` retorne lo mismo que `__str__`, la cadena de `__repr__` debe representar de forma inequívoca la instancia y por lo general ser un argumento válido para que `eval` pueda reconstruir la clase.
- Puedes usar anotaciones de tipos en vez de comentarios. Además de ser legibles para otros desarrolladores, puede ser usados por linters como MyPy para depurar el código.
- Sería apropiado que implementaras el resto de métodos para las comparaciones para que sus respectivos operadores funcionen como deben, `__le__()` (`<=`), `__gt__()` (`>`), `__ge__()`(`>=`), `__eq__()`(`==`), `__ne__()`(`!=`). Para ahorrarte tanto trabajo, puedes recurrir a decorar la clase con `functools.total_ordering` y solo agregar `__le__` y `__eq__`.
- Considera no usar mayúsculas para los nombres de atributos y métodos, CamelCase se reserva solo para nombres de clases, el resto debe usar `snake_case` (variables, métodos, atributos, funciones y nombres de módulos) o `SNAKE_CASE` (constante).

---

```
import functools


@functools.total_ordering
class BR:

    def __init__(
            self, nom: str, antecesor: str,
            concecuencias: str, inserir: list, eliminar: list
            ) -> None:
        self.n_regla: str = nom
        self.antecesor_str: str = antecesor
        self.antece_list: list = []
        self.concecuencias: str = concecuencias
        self.add_element: list = inserir
        self.del_element: list = eliminar

        if self.antecesor_str:
            self.gener_list()

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return (f'{self.n_regla} antecedentes:{self.Anteserores} '
                f'concecuencia:{self.concecuencia}')

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return (f"{self.__class__.__name__}"
                f"({repr(self.n_regla)}, {repr(self.antecesor_str)},"
                f" {repr(self.concecuencias)}, {self.add_element},"
                f" {self.del_element})")

    def __lt__(self, other: BR) -> bool:
        self_attrs = (len(self.antece_list), self.n_regla)
        other_attrs = (len(other.antece_list), other.n_regla)
        return self_attrs < other_attrs
        
    def __eq__(self, other: BR) -> bool:
        self_attrs = (len(self.antece_list), self.n_regla)
        other_attrs = (len(other.antece_list), other.n_regla)
        return self_attrs == other_attrs

    def gener_list(self) -> None:
        self.antece_list = self.antecesor_str.split('^')
```

> ```
> >>> lista = [BR("ccc", "h^i^j", "", [], []),
>              BR("bbb", "a^b^d^k", "", [], []),
>              BR("aaa", "a^b^c", "", [], []),
>              BR("ddd", "b", "", [], [])]
>
> >>> sorted(lista)
>
> [BR('ddd', 'b', '', [], []),
>  BR('aaa', 'a^b^c', '', [], []),
>  BR('ccc', 'h^i^j', '', [], []),
>  BR('bbb', 'a^b^d^k', '', [], [])]
> ```

Comment: Que diferencia hay entre utilizar el método sort() y sorted()? Yo utilizo el sort de esta forma nombre_lista.sort()

Comment: `list.sort` es un método propia de las listas y opera in place, `sorted` es una función built-in y sirve para cualquier iterable (incluidos generadores, iteradores, tuplas, etc)  cuyos items puedan ser ordenados entre si (no solo listas) y retorna una nueva lista con los items del iterable ordenados, no lo hace  in-place, por lo demás son iguales.